# display all cells in a mysql column

Tags: php, mysql

I need all values from a table column put into an assoc array. I am having trouble finding the answer.

the table is only six rows deep.
example:

```
|--id--|--name--|--A--|--B--|--C--|
|--01--|--xl33--| 1.30| 2.45| 4.40|
```

i would like to get an assoc array for column B

```
name[xl33]=2.45
name[xl34]=....and so on
```

The trick is that the form will tell the script which column to fetch. A,B,C,D,E,F OR G

I know i could re-format the table and accomplish what i want but I need it structured the way i have it.( i have left out some columns for simplicity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function return_column($letter){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT name, $letter FROM example") or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) {
        $return[$row['name']] = $row[$letter];
    }
    return $return;
}

$results = return_column('A');
print_r($results);
```

Comment: Changing `$row['B'];` to `$row[$letter]` would be better ?!

Comment: fan friggin tastic! Jleagle, Thank you! It will take me a few minutes of playing with this to full understand it but It works just like it should. ManseUK, your suggestion is spot on. Moving forward, Learning as I go.. Thanks to you guys and Stack..

Answer (score 1):

Something like :

```
$col = 'B';
$name = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $name[$row['name']] = $row[$col];

}
```

This creates an array `$name` and uses the `name` column as the key and the `$col` column for the value ...

Comment: this seems like it would work as well, I did however like the function slightly better. Thank you for taking the time!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) function.

Example/

```
$query = $this->query($YOUR_QUERY);
$returnMap = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { array_push($returnMap, $row); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_fetch_assoc` — Fetch a result row as an associative array.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         $data[$row["column1"]]= $row["column2"];

        ..............
        .........
    }
```